# Is it ok to change the chunk size of a download stream in the download loop in python-requests? And how could I iter_content more efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, download-manager

Im trying to Build a downloader application and i need help with request library here.

```
while total_bytes != n_bytes_read:

    header = {"Range": "bytes={}-{}".format(n_bytes_read, total_bytes+1 )}

    r = requests.get(self.url, headers=header,stream = True, timeout=(10,10))

    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
        if  (len(chunk) == chunk_size) or (n_bytes_read + len(chunk) == total_bytes):
            f.write(chunk)
            n_bytes_read += len(chunk)
            chunk_size *= 2
            update_progress_bar(n_bytes_read)
        else
            chunk_size = int(chunk_size / 2)
```

Im trying to speed up the download process but this part seems to hinder that

Comment: Once you have created the iterator by `r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size)`. You can't change its size.

Comment: So theres no other way to make the chunk_size more flexible throughout the download loop??

Comment: You can't use a variable before it's declared.  In `chunk_size=chunk_size`, the value of `chunk_size` hasn't been declared yet when the interpreter gets to that point, so your code doesn't even work.